# Unknown location error when importing .obj

Tags: import, error

I'm completely new to Blender but I'm trying to import an .obj (https://we.tl/t-X9g9ETJoBk) but I'm getting a `location: <unknown location>: -1` error message in the console when doing so.

How can I import this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The file you're trying to import has the extension .obj.py.  It is not a .obj so you can't import it like a normal object.  Go into the text editor view in blender, Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>O</kbd>, or go to *Text > Open Text Block* and open the `.py` file, then simply press *Run Script* or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: the file isn't showing in the text editor? im working with Mac if that makes any difference?

Comment: I'm unsure where you're running into a problem. Without your file I can't reproduce this to assist you.

Comment: I added file link if u wanna take a look?

Comment: @James I'm able to import your file with no problems. It may be your Blender installation.  You're going to File->Import->Wavefront(.obj), choosing your file and importing it , correct?  This works for me.

Comment: yeah doing exactly that. Although when I select both the .obj and .mtl file it imports but I cannot see the model in the viewport? thanks for ur help btw!